# Adding and/or logic into the criteria field (SUMIF)?

Tags: google-sheets

Using Google Sheets with the expression SUMIF, is there a way to make the criteria field look for 2 types of values using OR logic?

```
A    B  
Joe  1  
Joe  2  
Tim  3  
Roy  4  
Tim  5  
Roy  6
```

How do I make a SUMIF for the rows that have Joe and Roy so the result is 13?

Someone showed me how to do it on LibreOffice Calc simply with `=SUMIF(A1:A6;"=Joe|Roy";B1:B6)`, but that doesn't seem to work on Sheets. I've currently resorted to a query like so, `=sum(query(A:B,"Select B where A = 'Joe' or A = 'Roy'"))`, is there a simpler way with just incorporating the pipe |?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Use of REGEXMATCH**

There are many ways to do this in Google sheets. One is:

```
=SUM(filter(B:B,REGEXMATCH(A:A,"Joe|Roy")))
```

---

to make it with sumif:

```
=SUMIF(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"Joe|Roy")),true,B:B)
```

---

**Filter with OR logic**

and this formula is ok:

```
=sum(FILTER(B:B,(A:A="Joe")+(A:A="Roy")))
```

but it's not so easy to use when you want it matching more then 2 names.

---

**DSUM function**

To sum whith multiple criteria, use DSUM.

Prepare data A1:B7:

```
Name    Sum
Joe       1
Joe       2
Tim       3
Roy       4
Tim       5
Roy       6
```

Prepare range with conditions D1:D3:

```
Name
Joe
Roy
```

And use formula DSUM:

```
=DSUM(A1:B7,B1,D1:D3)
```

Comment: well that did the trick, thanks

why's regexmatch necessary in this scenario btw?

Comment: As said in help, `criterion can contain wildcards including ? to match any single character or * to match zero or more contiguous characters`, but nothing said about "|" char to match two or more values.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en) and [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en).

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"Joe|Roy"), B:B)
```

[image]

It works by first applying REGEXMATCH to every entry in `A:A`. This results in an array of TRUE (1) or FALSE (0) values as shown in column C and D. Then SUMPRODUCT is called which multiplies each 1 or 0 by the values in B:B as shown in the formula:

```
1*1 + 1*2 + 0*3 + 1*4 + 0*5 + 1*6 = 13
```